Adding Link to SharePoint Navigation Site via Powershell with Variables
I have a script which deploys a planner from a template to multiple SharePoint sites within my tenant. I would like to have a portion that adds a link to the planner to the Quick Launch of the site.
I added a section in the script to get the specific variables that makeup the planner URL:
https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/teams/GroupNameGoesHere/_layouts/15/Planner.aspx?groupid=GROUPIDGOESHERE&planid=PLANNERIDGOESHERE
So in the script I call the specific site where the planner has been created, selecting the id. Same for the planner ID as those are the variables in the link.
$groupid = get-pnpMicrosoft365Group -identity "Group Name" | select-object Id
$plannerid = get-pnpplannerplan -group "Group Name" -identity "2025 Plan" | select-object Id

I then create the link
add-pnpnavigationnode -title "2025 Planner" -url "/teams/GroupName/_layouts/15/Planner.aspx?groupid=$groupid&planId=$plannerid" -location "quicklaunch"

The link gets created, but it turns out like this:
/teams/GroupName/_layouts/15/Planner.aspx?groupid=@{Id=f9d04fb1-7fdc-4522-aedf-7dc0ef2a27d2}&planId=@{Id=7tFWKkguG02bzOFxp4lKa2QACTpB}
I have also tried calling the variables like this, which results in the same link:
add-pnpnavigationnode -title "Test Link" -url "/teams/GroupName/_layouts/15/Planner.aspx?groupid=$($groupid)&planId=$($plannerid)" -location "quicklaunch"


Add -ExpandProperty to you Select-Object calls
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Id
